# How to access C++ COM Object in C# Background worker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, marshalling, mta

I am developing a common c# COM component (dll) which can be consumed by any COM client. As part of this I m exposing a outgoing interface called ICallback.The client which is using my dll will implement the methods and provide the com object via incoming interface method,

For example,

Below are 2 interfaces exposed by my c# dll

```
interface IMyInInterface 
 {
      void Initialize(ICallback object);
 }

 interface ICallback
{
      void doSomething();
}
```

my c# dll implements IMyInInterface .

So client application calls Initialize method and passes ICallback pointer to IMyInInterface implementation .

My client is C++ atl dll which has implementation for ICallback.

**C++ Call:**

```
         .... 
         /* Code to create callbackImpl goes here */

         MyImplObj.Initialize(callbackImpl);
```

My c# dll is wpf dll. So when ICallback object is accessed in UI thread then it can able to call ICallback.Dosomething().It works fine.

**C# Implementation:**

```
class MyImpl : IMyInterface
{

...
            ICallback _Mycallback = null;

            void Initialize(ICallback callback)
             {
                 _MyCallback = callback         
             }

              Button_Click()
              { 
                 _Mycallback.DoSomething();       **// This works fine**
              } 
}
```

But Since Dosomething() is a long running task, I wanted to do this work in parllel, so I am using BackgroundWorker for this.

When the ICallback.Dosomething() is called from background worker as below, I am getting exception as the Interface not found,

```
class MyImpl : IMyInterface
    {

    ...
                ICallback _Mycallback = null;

                void Initialize(ICallback callback)
                 {
                     _MyCallback = callback         
                 }

                  Button_Click()
                  { 
                     //Code to create Background worker //

                    BackgroundWorker bkgrwkr = new BackgroundWorker();
                    bkgrwkr.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    bkgrwkr.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;            
                    bkgrwkr.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);

                    .....

                  } 

                  void Worker_DoWork()
                  {
                        _Mycallback.DoSomething();       **// This Fails**
                  }
    }
```

it fails with interface not found exception.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'ICallback'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface
>   call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{3B7C00E3-C145-4195-B9B4-984EAAC8954D}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

**Stack Trace:**

> at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc,
>   IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)    at
>   MyDLL.ICallback.DoSomething()

How to use com objects from Background worker? Even I tried to do something from Thread with appartment set as STA. the same error occurs.

Comment: Can you post the exception with stack trace?

Comment: How is your C++ ATL COM object declared with respect to apartments? STA, MTA? Who creates this COM object?

Comment: @Hans Passant I changed Apartment to Both in  C++ rgs file. Still it's same behaviour.

Comment: Did you call CoInitialize() for your background thread? It has to be called for every thread that wants to use COM.

Comment: @Zer0 Updated the exception and stacktrace in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause for this issue, The issue is due to BackgroundWorker uses Appartment as MTA. When I tried to get apartment state inside the Worker_DoWork using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() method, it returned MTA. This is root cause for the issue,

Now I have resolved the issue using Task as below, Using task the parallel execution also achieved.

```
       Button_Click()
       {  
           Task workerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
           () =>
           {
               DoWorkDelegate();
           }
           , CancellationToken.None
           , TaskCreationOptions.None
           , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
           ); 

           workerTask.wait();
       }

       void DoWorkDelegate()
       {
        _Mycallback.DoSomething();     // This works 
       }
```

Passing TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() resolves the issue. This ensures  sychronizationContext of Task as same as current context.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that code, run in a `BackgroundWorker`, runs on a thread in the thread pool, where the COM apartment model is not set.

I recommend you call your interface from a dedicated thread.  Use `Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);` before calling `Thread.Start()`.

Also, the object that you pass to `Initialize` must be created in the **same** thread.  If not, such objects need to be marshaled in a special was.  Find more details [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990/Understanding-Classic-COM-Interoperability-With-NE).